# IIS 6.0 Default webpage won't work

Tags: iis-6

In IIS 6.0 running on a server 2003 r2 the default webpage can't be found, but if I change the url to specifically go to the default page it works.

i.e. website.com doesn't work when defaultwebsite.html is set as the default website, but website.com/defaultwebsite.html works.

I've done simple stuff like enabled default content page and reset iis, but I'm not too familiar with it.

I have another website that works just fine that I compared the settings to. The only difference is that it is running on 32 bit and this new one is 64 bit. Are there any settings in particular that need to be changed or added to get the same functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it:

In the Windows registry, open the following node: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET\4.0.30319.0

Create a new DWORD value named EnableExtensionlessUrls.
Set EnableExtensionlessUrls to 0. This disables extensionless URL behavior.
Save the registry value and close the registry editor.
Run the iisreset command-line tool, which causes IIS to read the new registry value.

Make sure if you're on a 64 bit system that in the registry you are under the Wow6432Node and not just SOFTWARE:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\ASP.NET\4.0.30319.0\EnableExtensionlessUrls